# Time delayed forced auto approval

Tags: batch, approval-process

**UPDATE**: the code below will work as expected. The error was due to the typo in the action, it should be `Approve` instead of `Approved`.

**Original Question**: I am attempting to implement time delayed auto approval of a record. The current approach is to leverage a batch job for this. Executing the approval code in anonymous Apex does work however in the batch job context below error is thrown at line `Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);`.

Would anyone know how to resolve it? It seems that perhaps batch approach is the wrong avenue for this task - I am open to suggestions.

> First error: Process failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_OPERATION, Illegal transition type: []

Class excerpt:

```
global class ID_ApprovalSchedulable implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
    ...
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext oBatchableContext, List<cms__Approval__c> oApprovalBatchChunkList) {
        System.debug('>>> ID_ApprovalSchedulable.execute(Database.BatchableContext ...)');
        System.debug('=== ID_ApprovalSchedulable.execute(Database.BatchableContext ...): `oApprovalBatchChunkList.size()=' + oApprovalBatchChunkList.size() + '`');
        System.debug('=== ID_ApprovalSchedulable.execute(Database.BatchableContext ...): `oApprovalBatchChunkList=' + String.valueOf(oApprovalBatchChunkList) + '`');

        // get the work item list
        List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> oWorkItemList = [SELECT ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId IN :oApprovalBatchChunkList];
        System.debug('=== ID_ApprovalSchedulable.execute(Database.BatchableContext ...): `oWorkItemList=' + oWorkItemList + '`');       

        // auto approve the items
        for (ProcessInstanceWorkItem oWorkItemCurrent: oWorkItemList) {
            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
            oPWR.setComments('Auto approved through JobId: \'' + oBatchableContext.getJobId() + '\'');
            oPWR.setAction('Approved');
            oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemCurrent.ID);
            Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);                                
        }

        System.debug('<<< ID_ApprovalSchedulable.execute(Database.BatchableContext ...)');
    }   
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To approve using apex you need to set the next approverId. Also, the action should be 'Approve' instead of 'Approved'.

Code here:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
oPWR.setComments('Auto approved through JobId:');
oPWR.setAction('Approve');
oPWR.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemCurrent.ID);
Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);
```

Along with this, other possible solution can be **Workflow + Trigger**. Time dependent workflow making a field update which will invoke the apex trigger with approval process code similar to the one here in batch.

Comment: FACEPALM! it was the 'Approved' (instead of 'Approve') typo in my code. Thank you @Sikha

Comment: if the the approval process has intermediate step would you know how to skip them and go the the final approval step?